# Show vector in function

Tags: r

I have the following function which extracts values and calculates a correlation.

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
    getfiles <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE) # get all files
    for(i in 1:332){
            file<-read.csv(getfiles[i]) # read files
        end_result<-vector() # create vector
            complete <- sum(complete.cases(file)) # count # complete cases
        CompleteCaseOnly <- na.omit(file) #filter out NA values
            not_complete <-sum(!complete.cases(file))
        if(complete > threshold) {
            nit <- CompleteCaseOnly[,2]
                    suf <- CompleteCaseOnly[,3]
            corr <- cor(nit,suf)#determine correlation
            #print(corr)
                            end_result<-c(end_result, corr)#store in vector
        }   
        }       
 end_result #show_vector
}
```

I checked and everything works fine. The only thing which I can't get working is that I can print the vector `end_result`. I get a list of the correlations when I uncomment the `print(corr)` line but I just want output the vector.

Any clues on how I can make the function show the vector when I do fe corr("Assignment1")?

Answer (score 1):

You should create `end_result` outside the `for` loop and also should avoid growing it: `end_result <- rep(NA_real_, 332)` should be place before the loop and then you can do `end_result[i] <- corr` inside the loop.

Comment: you can't say end_result[i]<-cor because as per the problem description in coursera course the size of end_result may also be less than 332 since it checks for threshold

Comment: @VigneshKalai Just do `na.omit(end_result)` in the end (assuming you don't want to distinguish that case from actual `NA` values). However, if the correlation coefficients can't somehow be matched to the files, the result seems less than ideal.

Comment: yeah can you change that in your answer but is this faster than just growing the vector

Comment: If they teach growing objects in a loop in a Coursera course that makes me doubt its quality. That's probably the slowest operation possible in R.

Comment: Thanks ronald that helped a lot but what is the difference between NA and NA_real_

Comment: You could use `NA` too, since in this case R coerces to numeric as needed. `NA_real_` is an `NA` value of type numeric (double).

Comment: Thanks again so if I am  correct this will increase the speed

Comment: Marginally, since in this case `read.csv` is the slowest part of the code because the result vector doesn't get very big. However, one should always avoid bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time will remove my answer